# Create DotNetOpenAuth Oauth 2.0 Provider

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, provider

First, sorry if it’s not the correct way to ask some helps.
I’m currently playing with DotNetOpenAuth sources and samples and I’m not sure to know how to proceed. I know there are some questions alreadys asked about this need but any responses have helped me...

My need is quite simple to explain

An external web site needs to allow web users to log them by using our User accounts (login + password) as google or facebook do it.
This external web site request us to implement a OAuth 2.0 provider.

I’m pretty sure the best library with our current technology (.net) is to use this DotNetOpenAuth but I don’t understand all steps required for that.

I have tested some of samples like “OpenIdProviderWebForms” or “OAuth2/OAuthClient” but they don’t help me to make a good choice
and to know how start this Oauth 2.0 provider on server side (…)

Thanks for all helps,
Sb

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "OAuthAuthorizationServer" sample is the best choice in order to implement a provider with login + password.
Can someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same boat but here's a good starting point:

1. Set up OAuth 2.0 server ([Example of OAuth 2 Application](http://ngauthenticationweb.azurewebsites.net/#/home))

Then...

2. Configure the OAuth 2.0 server
   ([Sample Authorization Server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server))

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure this helps me a lot except for understanding the use and difference of AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer... And this sample does not use DotNetOpenAuth library

Answer (score 0):

I used [CustomOAuthClient](https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/CustomOAuthClient) to get me started.  I was eventually able to hook it up to my private OAuth2 server with a bit of hacking and debugging.